# Does mutual information capture interactions?

Tags: machine-learning, inference, signal-processing

Suppose I have a response $Y$ and two features, $X$ and $Z$. Individually the features are not very predictive but their interaction is strongly predictive. Something like

$$Y = 0.5X + 0.5Z + 20XZ + \epsilon$$

Will just $X$ and $Z$ still have high mutual information with $Y$ because of the interaction term or will only the dependency of $Y$ on $X$ and $Z$ separately be captured?

Answer (score 1):

In general, high (relatively speaking) mutual information between Y and (X,Z) does not imply high mutual information between Y and X or Y and Z.

Let X and Z be independent random variables. Let Y=XZ. Then the mutual information between Y and (X,Z) is ent(X,Z), but the mutual information between Y and X is 0.

OTOH, high mutual information between Y and X does imply high mutual information between Y and (X,Z).

I(Y,(X,Z)) >= I(Y,X)